# WSO2 Identity Server hook into the JIT provisioning process?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there a way to hook into the JIT provisioning process for example to let the user agree to the site's terms of use?

Scenario:  User logs in through social login (facebook, google ...) for the first time. The user gets automatically created via just in time provisioning without user interaction. The process should be intercepted to ask the user to read and accept the terms. 
What would be the best way to accomplish it?

Comment: Actually I solved that by writing an local authenticator and use it as the last step of a multi step authentication. If the user does not agree, the authentication will fail and the user is not provisioned.